# Optional id in Angular interface provides argument of type number undefined is not assignable to parameter of type number

Tags: angular, typescript

My interface has an optional Id:

```js
export interface UserAccount{
    // User infos
    id?: number;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    mail: string;
    genderId: number;
    gender?: Gender;
    password: string;
    userName: string;
    login: string;
    useraccountTypeId: number;
    userAccountType?: UserAccountType;
    name?: string;
    commercialmail?: string;
    phone?: string;
    vatnumber?: string;
    truckId?: number;
    truck?: Truck;
}
```

This interface is used to create  and update a user profile. My problem is that when I need to use the Id in the html part in a method I have the following message : argument of type number undefined is not assignable to parameter of type number.

What is the best practice to avoid this problem?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `ngIf` directive in your template

example:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="id">
// will render only if id is not (undefined,null,false and '')
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help hritik chokker. I didn't have think about this solution.

Comment: @Paintbox , this will also work, but i will recommend to directly use *ngIf="u.Id" because there might be a case when value is undefined so this condition will also become true as u.id !== undefined

Comment: Yes indeed. Thanks for your correction.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to hritik chokker, I used this solution :

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="u.id">
  <button type="button" id="details" class="btn btn-details" (click)="getUserDetails(u.id)">Details</button>    
</ng-container>

I am hoping this can help.
```